# Извлечь id из ссылки (из html кода)

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте! У меня такой вопрос: в цикле выводятся стихи (по 3 на странице), внизу каждого ссылка для редактирования с его id:

```
<a href='proverka_coda1.php?id=1>редактировать</a>
<a href='proverka_coda1.php?id=2>редактировать</a>
<a href='proverka_coda1.php?id=3>редактировать</a>
```

Мне нужно извлечь из кода эти id в форму добавления комментариев, чтобы потом вывести названия стихов по id в списке и пользователь мог выбрать один из 3 вариантов, к какому стиху относится коммент. Пожалуйста, если напишете код, разъясните что делается, а то я недавно php занимаюсь. Спасибо.

Вот код:

```
Тут выводится три элемента (стихотворения) на странице:
<?php
    printf("<h2 align='center' style='font-size:15px'>%s</h2><div style='text-align:center'>%s
    <p style='color:#A6A6A6; font-size:14px'>автор: <b>%s</b><br> добавлено: <b>%s</b><br>
     <b><a style='color:#A6A6A6; font-size:14px' href='proverka_coda1.php?id=%s'>редактировать >></a></b></p></div><p align='center'>Рейтинг:<img src='images/%s.gif'></p>

    <form style='text-align:center' action='pereschet7.php' method='post' name='vv'>
        <p class = 'pvote' >1<input name='score' type='radio' value='1'>2<input name='score' type='radio' value='2'>3<input name='score' type='radio' value='3'>4<input name='score' type='radio' value='4'>5<input name='score' type='radio' value='5' checked>
      <input class='sub_vote' name='submit' type='submit' value='Оценить'>
      <input name='id' type='hidden' value= '%s'>
       <input name='cat' type='hidden' value='$cat'>
        </p>
    </form><br>", $myrow['nazv'], $myrow['text'], $myrow['title'], $myrow['date'], $myrow['id'], $r, $myrow['id']);

    }
    while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Вот здесь в списке хотелось бы выводить названия стихов с id, чтобы пользователь выбрал. Нужны id этих трех стихов, что вывелись выше.

```
<p align='left' style='font-size:15px'><b>ДОБАВИТЬ КОММЕНТАРИЙ:</b></p>
<form action="commentavtorskie.php" method="post" name="form_com">
<p><label>Ваше имя:  </label><input name="author" type="text" size="25" maxlength="30"></p>
<p><label>Текст комментария: <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea name="text" cols="31" rows="5"></textarea></label></p><p>Введите сумму чисел с картинки:<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="<? echo $myrow5["img"]; ?>">&nbsp;
  <input name="pr" type="text" size="7" maxlength="5"></p>
  <input name="page" type="hidden" value="<? echo $page; ?>">
  <input name="cat" type="hidden" value="<? echo $cat; ?>">
<p><input name="sub_com" type="submit" value="Комментировать"></p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что мешает в том же цикле вывести ссылки в виде:

```
<a class="comment_post" data-id="YOUR_ID" href='proverka_coda1.php?id=YOUR_ID>редактировать</a>
```

А дальше js.

Но в общем, постановка задачи не понятная. Более подробно распишите Вашу проблему, по возможности скриншот сайта с пояснениями к действиям пользователя.

При клике на ссылку формата выше будет через js передаваться параметр data-id ссылки в форму добавления комментария к стиху.

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
$('a.comment_post').click(function(){
      post_id = $(this).data('id');
      $('#comment_form input[name=post_id]').value(post_id);
      destination = $('#comment_form').offset().top;
      $('body,html').animate( { scrollTop: destination }, 1100 );
      return false;
    })
});
```

В форму комментария добавить поле:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="post_id"/>
```

На стороне сервера, в файле обработки добавления комментария вытягивайте post_id и заносите его в БД. А после можете отправить автору email оповещение функцией mail()

**UPD #1**

В цикле выводим ссылки с параметром data-id:

```
<a class="comment_post" data-id="YOUR_ID" href='proverka_coda1.php?id=YOUR_ID>редактировать</a>
```

Форма комментирования:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('a.comment_post').click(function(){
          post_id = $(this).data('id');
          $('#comment_form input[name=post_id]').value(post_id);
          destination = $('#comment_form').offset().top;
          $('body,html').animate( { scrollTop: destination }, 1100 );
          return false;
        })
    });
</script>
<p align='left' style='font-size:15px'><b>ДОБАВИТЬ КОММЕНТАРИЙ:</b></p>
    <form id="comment_form" action="commentavtorskie.php" method="post" name="form_com">
    <p><label>Ваше имя:  </label><input name="author" type="text" size="25" maxlength="30"></p>
    <p><label>Текст комментария: <br> <textarea name="text" cols="31" rows="5"></textarea></label></p><p>Введите сумму чисел с картинки:<br><br><img src="<? echo $myrow5["img"]; ?>">
      <input name="pr" type="text" size="7" maxlength="5"></p>
      <input name="page" type="hidden" value="<? echo $page; ?>">
      <input name="cat" type="hidden" value="<? echo $cat; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="post_id"/>
    <p><input name="sub_com" type="submit" value="Комментировать"></p>
    </form>
```

На стороне сервера принимаем параметр `$_POST['post_id']`. Должно все сработать.

Comment: Код добавила

Comment: 1) в какой момент нужно извлечь ИД ссылки ? 
При нажатий на одного из них ? Все ИД ли надо извлечь сразу или только текущей ссылки ? Если при нажатий ссылки то вам надо как то обработать событие *onclick*( e.preventDefault(); return false;), чтоб было возможность работать с этими ИД дальше.

Comment: Так комментарий будет добавляться сразу к трем стихам? )) Зачем в форму комментирования передавать все три id?

Comment: Нет, пользователь выберет один из трех, и в обработчик полетит только один id. Поэтому-то и надо извлечь id.

Comment: Форма комментирования располагается на этой же странице, где и стихи?

Comment: Да, только мне нужно без каких либо действий со стороны пользователя, т.е. выводяться три стиха с id в ссылках, эти id извлекаются и заносятся в форму. Такое возможно?

Comment: Да, можно. Способ я описал выше. Нужно что бы Ваша форма комментирования имела id=comment_form

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Answer (score 2):

Можно же записать в php это дело зарание

```
<a class="edit" href="proverka_coda1.php?id='.$myrow['id'].'" data-id="'.$myrow['id'].'">
  редактировать »
</a>
...
<input type="hidden" id="edit_id" value=""><!-- Это та форма куда нам надо -->
```

Дальше если вы используете jQuery, то можно так:

```
$(function(){
    $(".edit").click(function(){
        var a = $(this).data("id");
        $("#edit_id").val(a);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Ну а если чистый javascript, то

```
window.onload = function(){
    a=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        if(a[i].getAttribute('class')=='edit')
        {
            b = a[i].getAttribute('data-id')
            a[i].onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById('edit_id').value = b;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И совет еще, стили лучше убрать в css, да и упростить громоздкие конструкции

Comment: Спасибо! Я про такое незнала, недавно ведь занимаюсь! Стили в css, просто некоторые неохота было отдельно описывать)

Comment: @Регина Ошибку синтаксическую допустил, подправил, а стили все таки лучше убрать в css, потому как на выходе получим кучу громоздкого и лишнего кода, что отразится на весе страницы.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_GET[id]  ---???, это имеется ввиду?
```

Comment: Нет не так, нужно извлечь id из html кода, т.е.:

<a href='proverka_coda1.php?id=1>редактировать</a>
<a href='proverka_coda1.php?id=2>редактировать</a>
<a href='proverka_coda1.php?id=3>редактировать</a>

Вот 1,2,3 нужно извлечь.